# blink the flashlight, make the flashlight app

Tags: ios

I am making a flashlight app.

Its functions are 1.on/off torch, 2.blink touch(with switch and slider)

Here is all my code

```
ViewController.m

//
//  ViewController.m
//  Just Flashlight
//
//  Created by CenoX on 2013. 10. 9..
//  Copyright (c) 2013년 SHIFTstudios. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.blinksliderlabel.text = @"150ms";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)flash:(UIButton *)sender {

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    if ([device hasTorch] == NO)
    {
        [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
        [_flashton setHighlighted:YES];
    } else {
        [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        [_flashton setHighlighted:NO];
    }
}

- (IBAction)blinkspeed:(UISlider *)sender {
    int progress = lroundf(sender.value);
    self.blinksliderlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dms", progress];
}
@end

ViewController.h

//
//  ViewController.h
//  Just Flashlight
//
//  Created by CenoX on 2013. 10. 9..
//  Copyright (c) 2013년 SHIFTstudios. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *flashton;
- (IBAction)flash:(UIButton *)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *blinksliderlabel;
- (IBAction)blinkspeed:(UISlider *)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *blinkswitch;


@end
```

How do I blink the torch(flashlight)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set an NSTimer.

Start with having a property for the NSTimer so you can invalidate it to get it to stop later.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *blinkTimer.
```

Here is a sample of how I create a timer in my code:

```
self.blinkTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(timerUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This will call timerUpdate every 0.3 seconds.

In timerUpdate you can turn on/off the flashlight.

When you want it to stop, just do `[self.blinkTimer invalidate];`